# using content_for and ajax/Jquery to partially update webpage

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl, mojolicious

I've been slowly learning Mojolicious and Perl thanks to the great help from those on this site. I have been trying to determine the best way to dynamically update parts of my page based on the results of Jquery get calls.

At the moment I have a template like this (Thanks to one of the Mojo contributors Joel)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  %= content
  %= include 'common_js'
  %= content_for 'js_imports'
 </body>  
</html>
```

Then I have a page that uses this layout, like below.

```
%title 'Script Test'; 
% content_for 'js_imports' => begin 
%= javascript begin 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input#testbutton").click(function(){ 
      $.get('<%= url_for('testbutton') %>', 
        function (data) { 
            $("div#content").html(data);  
         }); 
      }) 
   }); 
 % end 
 % end 

<p>Main Page</p> 
<input type="button" id="testbutton" class="btn btn-danger" value="test"> 
<div class="span9" id="content"></div><!--/span9-->
```

So when the 'testbutton' is clicked I am writing the response from the get request to the div with id content.

The 'data' I'm getting back is;

```
% content_for 'js_imports' => begin 
  %= javascript begin 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("input#testbutton2").click(function(){ 
        alert('testbutton2 clicked'); 
    }); 
    }); 
  % end 
% end    

<p>Test Button Clicked</p> 
<input type="button" id="testbutton2" class="btn btn-danger" value="test2">
```

Now, my javascript above isn't embedded in my page. I think its because content_for js_imports no longer exists in the DOM. I can add a 'content_for' tag to my test page, but then the script is added within my DIV with ID content. What I'm trying to achienve somehow is have my script added to the end of the page under my existing script. I know I can use javascript to add and remove script but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with tag helpers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to include that data your getting back in a content_for block. Just include it directly:

```
%= javascript begin 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input#testbutton2").click(function(){ 
      alert('testbutton2 clicked'); 
  }); 
  }); 
% end 

<p>Test Button Clicked</p> 
<input type="button" id="testbutton2" class="btn btn-danger" value="test2">
```

And if you don't want it to replace the existing content, but just append to it, then use `append` instead of `html`:

```
$("div#content").append(data);
```

Joel Berger (in the comments) created a nice [pastie](http://pastie.org/7168297) that shows what you want.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I appreciate the response. I may not have been clear in my question. What I want to do is add the returned HTML to div#content but put the javascript section returned after the existing javascript at the end of the page. I know if I was redrawing the whole page I could just reference the layout again but I want to just update part of the page.

Comment: The reason your initial javascript goes at the end of the file is to delay its parsing until the rest of the page has been downloaded. This is essentially aesthetic, so that the user sees the page even as the later javascript is being executed. Once the page has been rendered, new content loaded via ajax doesn't need to be at the end, and in fact I believe jQuery will munge it anyway. Ben is right, just include it where it is, content_for wont help here.

Comment: you should be rendering the response before returning it though, the browser wont know what to do with the templating directives.

Comment: Here is a pastie for you demonstrating what you want. Note that I pull in jQuery from google CDN. http://pastie.org/7168297

Comment: Yeah, as @JoelBerger said, it shouldn't matter where the javascript actually ends up being inserted. It's invisible to the user and works equally well anywhere. I also added the pastie to my post (with credit, of course -- thanks!).

Comment: @user1768233, just pinging you in case you didn't notice the comments on this post.

Comment: I Guys, thanks for the explanation. I was understand the impression that the order in which the javascript appeared in the page mattered. i.e if I want to use a Jquery function then the JQuery function need to be referenced first and therefore above it. I guess this way of thinking was wrong. Many thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @user1768233, the order in which the javascript is *executed* definitely does matter, but it is not always executed in the order it appears. In this case, any javascript in the later view is not executed until it is pulled into the page, and by that point, all other javascript has executed. Where in the page the javascript ends up is not important.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I think thats the problem I'm facing and I'm trying to work through. At the moment I have a layout which loads jquery (plus a bunch of other libraries). This layout is used by a page, but for some reason the scripts on the page must be loaded before my layout is?? because my script on the page is failing because I'm getting an error stating $ is not defined. I'm going to try to simplify my example, reproduce it and see if I can see where the issue is. If I can't I my post it here. Many thanks.